# localization and translation for backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, localization, marionette

I'm trying to figure out how to add localization with backbone.js and marionette. You can see the code in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6UpBP/) . I'm stuck as to how to display the translation from the json file to be displayed on the html page.

```
var TranslateForm = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

 TranslateForm.addRegions({
     form: "#form"
  });

  TranslateForm.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            lang: '' //the translation
        }
    });

   //create a View for our User model       
    TranslateForm.UserFormView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
       onBeforeRender: function(){
        var lang = this.model.attributes.lang;

        //let's get the json translation file before we render the view 
        $.getJSON("json/"+ lang +".json", function(data) {
            //data = this.model.locale;
            console.log(data);
        });
    },
    onRender: function(){

    },
    className: 'row',
    tagName: "div",
    template: "#translate_this"
    });

  TranslateForm.on("initialize:after", function(){

//initialize model
var form = new TranslateForm.User(
        {
              "lang": "en"
        }
);

//initialize view
TranslateForm.form.show(new TranslateForm.UserFormView({
        model: form
}));


  });


  TranslateForm.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have your request for the translation JSON file in the wrong place. Whatever code you put in there, the view would have already rendered by the time the data returns.

A potential quick fix would be to put the request for translation data within the initialize:after callback. And once the data is ready, construct the view and pass the translation in.

```
TranslateForm.on("initialize:after", function(){
    var lang = 'en';
    $.getJSON("json/"+ lang +".json", function(data) {
        var form = new TranslateForm.User();

        TranslateForm.form.show(new TranslateForm.UserFormView({
            model: form,
            translations: data
        }));
    });
}):
```

Also... you will want to override the `serializeData` function of your view so you can pass the translation data into the actual template, something like this:

```
serializeData: function(){
    var modelData = this.model.toJSON();

     modelData.translations = this.options.translations;

     return modelData;
},
```